# Django SQL Dealing

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm working in a Django app and want to query one of my models to perform data dealing.

I tried to perform

```
from django.db import connections

cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from Collections")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Got the following message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Could not understand the problem since I am already querying models in my views with QuerySet. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup django app before using connections:

```py
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project.settings")

# Initialize Django and load the settings
django.setup()

from django.db import connections

cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Collections")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: Should I Initialize Django and load the settings in the .py file that I am performing the query? If so, got "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup'". 'setup' is the project name.

Comment: @joaovitorpigozzo yes you should do it, make sure that you rename your_project.settings to your own settings.py file path to be able to run the code properly